# Unity3D 5.2 - IOS External Video in Native Player

Tags: ios, video, unity-game-engine

I am trying to include an external video, either streamed or downloaded and played in a Unity application. Previously I was using the Unity [Handheld.PlayFullScreenMovie](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Handheld.PlayFullScreenMovie.html) interface to play local videos, and thought this would be adequate to also play external video because the documentation (linked) states:

> The first parameter, path, can be a network-based URL.

I interpret this to mean that I am able to link to external resources?

However when I do the following:

```
Handheld.PlayFullScreenMovie("http://TheLinkToMyVideo.com/Video.mp4", Color.black, FullScreenMovieControlMode.Full, FullScreenMovieScalingMode.AspectFill);
```

The screen just goes black with no errors thrown.

I also found the this [plugin](https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/en/#!/content/9555) which I thought would be the answer, however the comments state that it is not compatible with Unity5+.

Also, Because it is IOS, I can't use movieTextures, which rules out using [WWW](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/WWW.html).

Any help much appreciated,

Cheers,
Zze

Comment: have you tried this on a device?

Comment: maybe your video does not follow any of the compression standards as mentioned in the documentation? http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Handheld.PlayFullScreenMovie.html

Comment: maybe you need to include www. after http:// ? and may be it's the NSAppTransportSecurity that blocks the connection (shouldn't be problem in the editor though)

Comment: @NikaKasradze Yes, I have been compiling and running it on IOS. I don't think its the compression because it works when its local. I will have to look at the NSApp TransportSecurity as I've never heard of that.